# LineCollection not displaying data for some axes on multiple axes plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code will create a plot that appears to have invisible data on several if the subplots.

- Why do I then need to include `ax[i].autoscale_view(True,True,True)`?
- Why does `print ax[i].lines` show `[]` ?

### Code

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# example data with properties:
# len(lines) == 4 and len(lines[0]) == 10
# len(x) == 10
lines = [(1.2310957583605482, 1.283772297331087, 1.61856069891319, 2.1602226857314735, 1.0277068564151643, 1.1715166081037471, 1.463648931121718, 1.2329321041327499, 1.4080120164965291, 1.2225064185740224), (0.33323810593968223, 0.32582779060567746, 0.32836534361310366, 0.51831090602571572, 0.29791484909192673, 0.35713207695246518, 0.29463171650130665, 0.34633265872428215, 0.39298012050485071, 0.410877623134692), (10, 11, 13, 17, 8, 10, 12, 10, 11, 10), (0.9911659269366481, 0.989291500800633, 0.9880005820749531, 0.9820511801663299, 0.978444258093041, 0.9737543029212308, 0.9711834357704919, 0.9632772617693266, 0.95740331184712, 0.9523058427743931)]
x = [0.0, 0.00101010101010101, 0.00202020202020202, 0.0030303030303030303, 0.00404040404040404, 0.00505050505050505, 0.006060606060606061, 0.007070707070707071, 0.00808080808080808, 0.00909090909090909]

n=len(lines) # copy in lines and x data from below
fig, ax = plt.subplots(n, sharex=True, figsize = (8, 8))
for i, y in enumerate(lines):
    xy = zip(x, y)
    lc = LineCollection([xy], linewidth = 2)
    ax[i].add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note: The question was originally concerning why data was 'invisible' on several subplots. It was only through formulating a minimal example for this question that I realised the autoscale wasn't being triggered on some of the subplots. For this reason I've left the more general title so that it can be found by those wondering why data is not being displayed.